# PHP variable for file name in fopen(). File name can not be empty error

Tags: php, fopen, filepath

I have a loop that displays every file in a php server as a link. Clicking the link opens the file using `fopen`like this:

```
  <?php
  echo"<ol>";
  if ($handle = opendir('saves/')) {
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
              echo '<li style"display:block"><a href="#codeword">'.$entry.'</a></li><br>';


    }
}
closedir($handle);
  } 
  echo"</ol>";
  echo'<div id="codeword">';
  $file = $entry;
  $f = fopen($entry, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
  // read file line by line until the end of file (feof)
  while(!feof($f))
  {
    echo fgets($f)."<br />";
  }

  fclose($f);
  echo"</div>";



  ?>
```

But when i run it i get the error

> fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty

I try to echo  `$entry` instead of the `fopen` and it appears as expected. So the problem is maybe the path to the file. What filepath am i supposed to use.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message is precise. This is _not_ a path issue, that would lead to a "file not found" error.

Comment: So what else could it be. I am sure that the right filename is beeing sent to the div. @arkascha

Comment: I doubt that. The anchor refers to `href="#codeword"`. There is _no_ file name in that. The issue arises because you make the old mistake to code multiple part of logic in a single file. Don't. Use one logic to create the list, one to process the click.

Comment: I tried to do it that way cause I'm not sure how to send the variable to the other file. If I use ajax for example. @arkascha

Comment: So instead of figuring out how a http get request is done you simply left it away and claim then things should work? Well...

Comment: The reason why the variable `$entry` is empty when you attempt your `fopen()` call is that the last call to `readdir()` returns `false`.

Comment: I actually tried to figure it out but if I do it that way it is a lot harder cause there are more things to figure out. So i decided to try doing it like this. @arkascha

Comment: Correct indention would make this much easier to read.

Comment: I am sorry for this, as you see I'm new to php. @Eiko

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in php documentation for `fopen()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php your first parameter is your filename.

Maybe your value `$entry` is null or empty.

Comment: Thats wath I thought at first, but I trieyd to echo it in the div an it was the exact file name. So it is not empty.

Comment: This is not an answer at all. It might have been a comment, though it does state nothing except the obvious which the OP already addressed in the question.

Comment: Did you check the type of your `$entry` ?

Comment: Did you try this `print_r($_FILES);` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, `$entry` will always be `false` (if it enters the `while`) or `undefined` (if it doesn't), as the `while` loop will never end until it is `false`

Comment: That is not correct. The loop will end as soon as the folder has been read to the end. Apart from that... why should an endless loop influence the content of a variable? And... the error is thrown in the code lines below that loop, so how can the loop be endless?

Comment: This loop is wokring pretty fine for me. So I dont think the problem is there.

Comment: @arkascha The loop `while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))` will only end iff $entry will be set to false.

Comment: @Eiko That is correct. And that will happen the moment no more entry is left in the folder to be read. You are right however that this sets `$entry` to `false`.

Comment: @arkascha And that's what Vicente says here. Because later on, Niki wants to open a file named $entry (=== false).

Comment: @Eiko You are right. My Fault. I miss understood Vincents explanation! I do apologize.

Comment: So what do you recommend me to do? :)